# Excel VBA User Defined Function with Decimal type Parameters

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-functions

I am writing a user-defined function in VBA in Excel. The parameters I will pass this function when it is called are decimal values. For example:

```
Public Function fcn(param1 as Decimal, param2 as Decimal)
   ...
End Function
```

But I cant seem to define my parameters as Decimal type?

Comment: As an alternative, you could just declare the parameters as `Double`

Answer (score 3):

From the VBA Language Reference for **EXCEL 2010**:

> **Note:**
>   At this time the Decimal data type can only be used within a
>   Variant, that is, you cannot declare a variable to be of type Decimal.
>   You can, however, create a Variant whose subtype is Decimal using the
>   CDec function.

Visual Basis for Applications Language Reference
  -> Visual Basic Language Reference
  -> Data Types
  -> Decimal Data Type

This has been the case for several versions of EXCEL (at least since Office 97), and so I do not expect it to change in the near future.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
Dim d as Variant
d = CDec(1.21)
```

Comment: Oh, so I just define my parameter as type Variant instead of Decimal?

Comment: That is the only way.